# Power Bi graph like pivot graph

Tags: graph, powerbi

I'm new to Power Bi, followed most of the tutorial on MS but haven't figured yet how creat a graph that resembles this graphic I did with **Excel** - **Pivot Graph**, using as source the same data table.

What I need to recreate in **Power Bi** is a column graph with the most requested (pre-orders requests % of total sum) products in different price ranges.

[Pivot Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TjUlM.jpg)

Table ie.

```html
| Date | Product | 3 to 5 Eur | 5 to 8 Eur | 8 to 11 Eur |
----------------------------------------------------------
| mar17| Coffe   |     12     |     7      |       2     |
| mar17| Milk    |     15     |     3      |       1     |
| mar17| Honey   |     17     |     0      |       5     |
| mar17| Sugar   |     20     |     9      |       8     |
```

Thank in advance for the help.

Bests,

Alberto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit - Thanks to Mike Honey for pointing out the original request was for % of grand total. I have added an additional step to accomplish this and cleaned up some existing steps.

When I imported your sample data into Power BI, I got this (looking at the data in the [Query Editor](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-desktop-query-overview/) window).

[image: Start]

From there, Select the Data and Product columns and then click on Transform -> Unpivot Columns -> Unpivot Other Columns...

[image: Unpivot]

... which results in this.

[image: Unpivot results]

Just to clean this up, I renamed the Attribute and Value columns and changed the data type of the Value column. In the end, it looks like this.

[image: Clean results]

Then just click on Home -> Close & Apply to get back in the [Report Editor](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-service-the-report-editor-take-a-tour/) window, where you can create a graph and configure it as shown such:

- Axis:

  - Price Range
  - Product
- Value:

  - Quantity

[image: Graph]

Then click of the forked, drill-down arrow in the top left corner of the graph to show Price Range and Product.

[image: Drilled Down Arrow]

Which looks like this.

[image: Drilled Down Graph]

Next, while not necessary I feel that it is very nice, with the graph selected, click on the paint roller icon and expand the X-Axis category. In there, turn off Concatenate labels.

[image: Nicer graph]

Finally, to get the bars to be % grand total, simply right click on Quantity in the Value section of the graph's fields and then select Show value as -> Percent of grand total.

[image: % total]

To get the final results that look like this.

[image: Final graph]

Comment: Do all of the above, then right-click the Quantity in the Value well and choose Show value as > Percent of grand total.

Comment: Thanks @MikeHoney for pointing that out. I've updated my answer to show the values as % of grand total.

Comment: Your step by step guide is great and helped me to solve the issue. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Alberto.F. - I'm glad I could help. You can help me (and the community) by accepting my answer if it took care of your question.